# Artifactory: How to only allow AD users from a specific group access

Tags: ldap, artifactory

I need to grant a group of people access to our repositories. Unfortunately I'm neither an LDAP nor an Artifactory expert. I hope you can help

I managed to grant access to all users and have specific permissions for everyone in the specified group, but I only want people from the group to be able to log in.

The users are in various groups in the hierarchy and somewhere in the hierarchy there's also that group.

works but doesn't filter the way I'd like it to
Search Filter (SAMAccountName={0} 
Search Base OU=_XYZ

don't work:
Search Filter: (&(SAMACcountName={0})(memberOf=CN=locationOfGroup))
Search Base: OU=_XYZ

Search Filter: (member={0})
Search Base: location of group

I sincerely have no idea how to do this - and to be honest, I have no idea what I'm doing. 
Anyone able to help?

EDIT: Sry, I forgot: I'm not getting any good log info, just "bad credentials" when I try a test users with those options. I can't find a way to get any better log info

Answer (score 1):

So I got a tip from a friend (sometimes rl provides faster answers than the whole wide internet ;) and it works. It was a variation of something I had already tried:

Base: _XYZ
Search Filter: (&(SAMACcountName={0})(objectclass=person)(memberOf=CN=locationOfGroup))

and the location of the group was given as a whole "address" not just from the base up. Plus adding the objectclass made all the difference